# Does RAM take the same time to extract 16bit or 128bit?

Tags: cpu, ram, cpu-architecture, mov

Modern x86 CPU with SSE and AVX/2 has tons of registers
[image: Table of registers]

**If I decide to use some of the biggest register (> 128bit) will my program slow down? Why?**

I can't find a unique solution. If I understand correctly, depending on the model, the CPU extracts a certain amount of RAM each time (64, 128bit) but only if you use the bits you asked for. **Is it right?**

If possible, apply your explanation to this example:

```
mov al, 0xFF ;8bit ns=??
mov ax, 0xFFFF ;16bit ns=??
mov eax, 0xAABBAABB ; 32bit ns=??
mov rax, 0xAABBCCDDAABBCCDD
mov xmm0, ...
mov zmm0, variable512bit
; and the opposite
mov variable512bit, zmm0
```

Comment: It depends on how wide the load/store unit is. If the unit is shorter than the register size, then it needs to be split into smaller operations. For example, Sandy Bridge as well as all AMD Bulldozer-line processors only have 128-bit wide load/store despite supporting 256-bit registers.

Comment: *RAM*, *Register*, and *Cache* are not the same thing at all. Please clarify what you mean and where, since you seem to use them interchangeably. Also remember that the CPU itself doesn't implement that X86 assembly directly, it translates it to micro-code instructions at runtime during the decode operation. The time it takes to perform these operations will vary *wildly* from CPU design to CPU design.

Comment: I mean, on my Intel/AMD cpu support up to 512bit registers, the time taken loading data from/sendinf data to RAM memory, is **the same for any size** or **is the same up to xxbits, then the time grows linearly** or **no, extract less bits always takes more/less time**

Comment: @Mignus Unless you have a Xeon Phi or you work for Intel, your CPUs don't have 512-bit registers. They haven't been released yet.

Comment: @Mysticial My CPU doesn't support neither AVX(1), so probably I haven't any 256bit register :) If you can, take a look at the comment in eckes answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time required to fill a register from the L1 cache depends on the processor-L1 cache interface. The width of the processor-L1 interface is usually equal or smaller than a cache line. In Nehalem, you can load 16 bytes in one cycle even though cache line size is 64 bytes wide. Take a look [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6355/intels-haswell-architecture/9) for some numbers for different architectures.

To answer your question with the assumption of L1 hit: As long as register size is equal or smaller than the processor-L1 interface, it does not slow down your code. Remember that if your access is not aligned, you incur two accesses to get data and that slows down your code.

In case of cache miss, the memory interface dictates your code performance. Note that memory bandwidth is much lower than cache bandwidth.

SIMD registers (like AVX and SSE) could be wider than the processor-L1 interface.

Comment: AMD's Bulldozer/Piledriver microarchitectures have two 128-bit ports but support 256-bit AVX (YMM) registers, so it is not unheard of for SIMD registers to be wider than the L1 interface.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Thanks for the comment. I just edited the post to fix this.

Comment: You might want to add that such assumes a cache hit. If the accesses are cache misses (as [eckes' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24963517) assumes), then as he indicated one would be limited by the memory interface and not the cache interface.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton just added that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your CPU will fetch cache lines from RAM if the data required is not already in the caches. On recent x64 the cache line is 64 byte. So using wider registers takes the same time for reading from memory, and possibly less time for processing the data (if you need all of it).

Having said that, some of the advanced opcodes might have different (more) clock cycles or less opportunities for out-of-order/parallel/predictive processing. Not sure for MOV. But typically if you need to optimize in this area, you also want to look at SIMD - which has its own performance characteristics.

And as discussed in the comments, it is not always best to use larger registers, as it might also make sense to use as much registers as possible, therefore using the smaller ones for smaller data items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) So I'm right if I say that the "perfect" size for **mov instruction** on x86 architecture is 64bit (the one loading faster), with the exception of SIMD instruction that can takes different times (usually more, sometimes equals, never less)?

Comment: Following what @Mysticial said, is it more important the load/store unit (up to 128bit, Sandy Bridge) or that any cache line is 64bit?

Comment: I guess its too complicated to answer with yes/no (and I am not experienced enough). For example if you "waste" the bigger registers for no good reason or if you need to do unaligned access or carry bits it might be better to use smaller registers.

Comment: @Mignus, a cacheline is usually 64 Bytes, not bits. It takes exactly the same time to load no matter what size you use out of it

Comment: Ok but every time I load something from the memory, does it load 64B? And then does it get the only xx **bits** it needs?

Comment: @eckes your answer is not correct. The interface between CPU and L1 cache is smaller than a cache line. Since registers are smaller than a cacheline, there is no need to fetch an entire cache line.

Comment: @aminfar there might be a CPU which can load a register without using the L1 data cache, can you name any? There might also be a CPU which can load and manage a partial cache line. Can you name any? I guess for writing it is more common to write partial changes (write through - which have the size of the data bus, for example 8 bytes). For reading you would need to turn off the caching, not something you do for normal ops.

Comment: (besides I was talking about loading the cache line from memory, not the register from cache. Since the memory access is the real slow thing.)

Comment: Actual memory access assumes a cache miss (which may or may not be common for a given workload). If read-for-ownership is avoided (e.g., using `dcbz` on Power or `wh64` on Alpha [RIP]; I don't think x86 provides this feature), then a write miss is avoided.  For memset-like operation, this would be significant. (In theory hardware could speculate that unwritten portions will not be read. This requires support for storing smaller chunks, e.g., using a write buffer or using fine-grained line sectoring. A write buffer would work well enough for streaming writes.)